# underscore groupby making json object missing

Tags: json, group-by, underscore.js, grouping

I have an json object fetching from server side, with all the nested data included. but after I use underscore groupby to group my object based on an attribute(say startTime here), the return array is being changed(my nested data are missed and being replaced as "[object]").

before it's being grouped:

```js
var objs = 
[{  id: '551de304e4b',
category: 'Restaurant',
title: 'Hurricane',
location: 'Darling harbor',
checkListItems: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
startTime: Wed Dec 02 2014 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST),
detailRestaurant: 
   { id: '551de304e4b',
     name: 'Hurricane',
     telphone: '020-3455555' } 
},
{   id: '551de301e4b',
category: 'Restaurant',
title: 'The Grill',
location: 'Darling harbor',
checkListItems: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
startTime: Wed Dec 03 2014 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST),
detailRestaurant: 
   { id: '551de301e4b',
     name: 'The Grill',
     telphone: '020-0009998' } 
}];
```

after it's being grouped:

```js
{'1417449600000': 
   [ { id: '551de304e4b',
       category: 'Restaurant',
       title: 'Restaurant',
       location: 'Hurricane',
       checkListItems: [Object],
       startTime: Wed Dec 02 2014 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST),
       detailRestaurant : [Object] } ],
 '1417536000000': 
   [ { id: '551de304e4b',
       category: 'Restaurant',
       title: 'Restaurant',
       location: 'Hurricane',
       checkListItems: [Object],
       startTime: Wed Dec 03 2014 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST),
       detailRestaurant : [Object] } ]
}
```

my groupby function looks like this:

```js
function groupByStartTime (objs){
    var objs = _.sortBy(objs, function(obj){
        return obj.startTime;
    });
    // objs in here is correct with all nested data
    var groups = _.groupBy(objs, function(obj){
        return obj.startTime;
    });
    // nested data within groups here is being folded 
    return groups;
}
```

Comment: yes, it's an array, the snippet above is only a part of the array. I didn't write it out completely.

Comment: the objects are fetched from server side, so it would be too complicate to set up a working example(App key etc will be needed). checkListItems are also from server side, and it's an array, after groupby function, checkListItems are being folded too... seems like all attributes which are not string will be folded as [object]

Comment: Then produce an equivalent example, the logic looks fine (https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/gv5fqtqd/) so something is going on in code that we can't see.